# How to load a dynamic saved dropdown during edit

Tags: ajax, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

In my app, i have a chained dropdown in which i am getting the second dropdown via jquery ajax, which works well.So i am trying to edit this saved data and load it back to an edit form, but the dropdown is showing empty. This is what i have done so far

Here is my model.py

```
class SchoolFees(models.Model):
  fid = models.ForeignKey(FacultyData, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, null=True)
  did = models.ForeignKey(DepartmentData, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, null=True)
  sid = models.ForeignKey(SessionData, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, null=True)
  amount = models.CharField(max_length=30)

  def __str__(self):
     return self.amount
```

forms.py

```
class FeesCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
   fid = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=FacultyData.objects.all(), empty_label="--Select Faculty--",
                             widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

   did = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=DepartmentData.objects.all(), empty_label="--Select Faculty First--",
                             widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

   sid = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=SessionData.objects.all(), empty_label="--Select Session--",
                             widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

   class Meta:
     model = models.SchoolFees
     fields = ['sid', 'fid', 'did', 'amount']

     widgets = {
        'amount': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter Amount'})

    }

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     super(FeesCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     self.fields['did'].queryset = DepartmentData.objects.none()

    # Get did queryset for the selected fid
     if 'fid' in self.data:
        try:
            fd = int(self.data.get('fid'))
            self.fields['did'].queryset =  DepartmentData.objects.filter(fid_id=fd).order_by('id')
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            pass # invalid input from the client; ignore and use empty queryset
```

Here is my view.py

```
def edit_fee(request, pk):
   app = settings.CONFIG
   post = get_object_or_404(SchoolFees, pk=pk)
   if request.method == 'POST':
     form = FeesCreationForm(request.POST, instance=post)
     if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.add_message(request, messages.WARNING, "Fees record updated successfully")
        return redirect('bursary:create_fee')

   else:
     # bring edit form out
     form = FeesCreationForm(instance=post)
     table = FeesTable(SchoolFees.objects.all())
     RequestConfig(request, paginate={'per_page': 10}).configure(table)
     context = {"form": form, "fees": table, 'app': app}


return render(request, 'editfee.html', context)
```

I expect that the saved value is pass to the dropdown with other form fields which are already showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through [this post](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html), i was able to solve it when reading the comments. All i needed was to add a backward relationship to my init function.

```
class FeesCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
  fid = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=FacultyData.objects.all(), empty_label="--Select Faculty--",
                             widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

  did = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=DepartmentData.objects.all(), empty_label="--Select Faculty First--",
                             widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

  sid = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=SessionData.objects.all(), empty_label="--Select Session--",
                             widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

  class Meta:
     model = models.SchoolFees
     fields = ['sid', 'fid', 'did', 'amount']

     widgets = {
        'amount': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter Amount'})

    }

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     super(FeesCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     self.fields['did'].queryset = DepartmentData.objects.none()

     # Get did queryset for the selected fid
     if 'fid' in self.data:
        try:
            fd = int(self.data.get('fid'))
            self.fields['did'].queryset =  DepartmentData.objects.filter(fid_id=fd).order_by('id')
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            pass # invalid input from the client; ignore and use empty queryset
    elif self.instance.pk:
        self.fields['did'].queryset = self.instance.fid.departmentdata_set.order_by('id')
        #backward relation - for this faculty selected, check its deparm
        #every department has its faculty
        # #in other word, which dept has their foreign key pointing to the current instance of faculty
```